# functional programming and self-commenting code - is this really possible?

Tags: functional-programming

As I got a lot of spare time to spend ATM I read a few threads/comments on code-comments and documentation here.
As most people here I too think that you should write your code so that it's easy to read and self-commenting as far as it's possible.
On the other hand I am a huge FP-fanboy - and yes if you write your code the right way it will be very readable in FP - or so I thought.
Problem is that tiny things make a awful lot of difference in FP-world. If your colleague doesn't fully understand FP he might be able to "read" the indentation of the code but won't be able to modify or fully understand it. That stands for languagues like Haskell, where a '.' or '$' makes a big difference and also for languages like F# or even C# of VB.NET with lots of LINQ statements.

At first glance the problem might be, that your peer just doesn't get the language and it's not the codes fault - on the other hand: who truly gets all of FP? Look at some papers concerning Haskell - the code is beautifully crafted and self-commenting but just as in math you may have to chew on a line for several minutes before you get it.

Of course in those papers there will be a text-block trying to clarify just after the code ....

So IMHO you have to comment your FP-code as long as you work in a shop where not every colleague has a PhD in CS ;)

What do you think?

PS: first post here - really looked for answers concerning this questions but didn't find any - please be gentle if I just didn't look hard enough :)

Comment: "Self-commenting" code is impossible, by definition. Code is all about "what?" and "how?", whereas comments should cover "why?" and "why not?". That's what Literate Haskell and alike is for.

Comment: well then give your functions/methods names like f1, f2, ...

Comment: Giving readable names is not nearly enough to render a code "self-explaining".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functional languages greatly favor the development of self-documenting code, because you can freely rearrange the order of functions, and easily abstract out any given part of the code, assigning it an explanatory name.

Abstract, abstract, abstract, is the keyword to master code complexity, and that's where the functional style shines. But there will be always things that cannot be expressed within the code itself.

One clear example is code for algorithms. It is unlikely that one can easily understand a complex algorithm just by looking at the implementation. Yes, functional languages make understanding simpler, becasue many gory details (trivial example: memory management) do not have to be coded explicitly, thus exposing the underlying logic more clearly.

However this is no substitute for an explanation in natural language, which conveys in an intuitive way how it works (and sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words). This is becasue our brain needs to observe difficult concepts from different point of views in order to understand them fully.

What to comment also depends on your audience. Beginners, average programmers or wizards? There is no one-fits-all solution.

E.g. you should explain the meaning of a "." (function composition) in Haskell if you are writing tutorial code, but certainly that would be a redundant explanation for anyone who has gone past chapter one/two of any Haskell book.

On the other hand some specific algorithm, like say red-black trees, could be a given for some programmers, and something very mysterious for others. In the second case you should add many comments to the code, or point to a document with further explanations.

Finally, one should notice that there is no consensus even among the masters. E.g.  Dennis Ritchie is famous for being extremely parsimonious with comments, instead Don Knuth is an advocate of "Literate programming", where comments are as important as code itself. A set of rules will never be a substitute for personal taste.

Comment: thank you - I guess I have to rethink some of my implementations - I tend to "crowd the line" with to much lambdas. Might be clearer if I really give a name to some small pieces of functionality.